# Rails admin encoding error when i try to use 'windows-1250'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, utf-8, rails-admin

I got error :_ incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and Windows-1250_
when i try to show something with chars from Poland ie. 'ąęźć'

in my application.rb i got:
config.encoding = "windows-1250"

In database.yml:
encoding: windows-1250

How can i show params in windows-1250 in rails admin panel?

Comment: What is your OS encoding and what is the ruby encoding?

I highly suggest you do not use CP1250 and stick with UTF-8

Comment: I'm making app on top of exisiting database so i cant change encoding. <br> When i make string in console for this app and execute string.encoding i got:  #<Encoding:CP852>

Comment: Please provide more context, like a full stacktrace. Something is coming in in UTF-8 and is then converted to CP1250, it seems. But hard to tell.

You can try and set the encoding flag to "-E CP1252" when starting your server.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you go with utf-8 encoding (which is ruby's default these days).

Your input 'ąęźć' is a valid utf-8 string, so you would face no problem in decoding it as a utf-8 string.

If you still want to hack around, you can use:

`'ąęźć'.mb_chars.tidy_bytes.to_s`

which should also give you the desired output.

Comment: I'm making app on top of exisiting database so i cant change encoding.